# Complex Object to List Mapping in automapper - RESTAPI

Tags: c#, automapper

Below is my Source object

```
public class Source
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime GeneratedFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime GeneratedTo { get; set; }

}
```

Then the Destination object

```
public class Destination
{
    public DateTime Day{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

The Date in the destination gets its value from `Source.GenerateFrom` and `Source.GenerateTo` (iterating until `Source.Generatefrom <= Source.GenerateTo`using while loop). Finally, I need a list of objects as below.

```
{"Day":"2019-02-04","name":"abc"},
{"Day":"2019-02-05","name":"abc"},
{"Day":"2019-02-06","name":"abc"}
```

Can this be achieved using automapper?

Below is the mapper profile class with the whileloop. Not sure if this is the right approach

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.forMember(
 dest => dest.Day,
 opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GenerateFrom))
 .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
 {
     var StartDate = src.GenerateFrom;
     var EndDate = src.GenerateTo;

     List<Destination> list = new List<Destination>();
     while(Startdate <= EndDate)
     {
        var data = new Destination {Day = StartDate, name = src.Name};
        list.Add(data);
        StartDate.AddDays(1);
     }
 });
```

Comment: Show us your while loop

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Updated the post with the mapper profile

Answer (score 0):

You can register this mapping for Your objects, if `Day` always get it's value from `GeneratedFrom` property. (Or modify it according to Your needs)

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                    .ForMember(d => d.GeneratedFrom, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Day))
                    .ForMember(d => d.Name, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Name));
```

Then If You want to get a list of objects where `Source.Generatefrom <= Source.GenerateTo` You need to use `System.Linq` expression:

```
var destList = sourceList.Where(x => x.GeneratedFrom <= x.GeneratedTo)
                         .Select(_mapper.Map<Destination>).ToList();
```

Then serialise it using `Newtonsoft.Json` library:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(destList);
```

Comment: You can simply call `Map` on the `IEnumerable`, there is no need for `Select` and `ToList`.